# Google Photos using up too much data and at the same time hangs on uploads even when on wifi

Tags: mobile-data, vpn, google-photos

Two problems related to the Google Photos App:

1. It often hangs on uploading saying "waiting for wifi" even though the phone is connected to wifi
2. According to "Mobile data usage" in settings, Photos is using a lot of mobile data

To me it almost seems like 1. and 2. contradict each other. I use an always on VPN.